# What is a carton of cigarettes in French?

Tags: vocabulaire

What would you call "carton of cigarettes" in French?

[image: carton of cigarettes]

Is it "cartouche de cigarettes" (f)?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're not sure if cartouche is correct? If you [google "cartouche de cigarettes"](https://www.google.com/search?q=cartouche+de+cigarettes&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjdk_6Jn-XPAhWGKWMKHeoTB9EQ_AUICSgC&biw=1600&bih=770) you get plenty of images of cartons.

Comment: I have edited the post after discussing it with a native speaker from another site.

Comment: And what did you find when you looked up [*cartouche de cigarettes*](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-anglais/cartouche%20de%20cigarettes) in a dictionary? ["Carton of cigarettes"](http://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/carton+of+cigarettes.html) on linguee.

Answer (score 3):

Yes that's correct.

A pack of cigarettes is:

> un paquet de cigarettes (m)

And a carton of cigarettes is:

> une cartouche de cigarettes (f)

Answer (score 2):

**1 pack:** un paquet de cigarette

**1 set of 10 packs (-> carton):** une cartouche de cigarette.

**On your picture:** une cartouche de 10 paquets de cigarette.

Comment: I disagree. A carton of cigarettes is a _cartouche_, and a pack is a _paquet_. See for instance [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cigarette_pack#Carton).

Comment: Edited, I have not the better English ever.